# Empty list when I supposed to have appended a lot of text to it

Tags: python, string, list

So I am working on a code to make a specific xml document turn into a html document for presenting a story. I have managed to get most of the way there, but when I go from concatenating a list into a string and append that new string into a list, the list is empty. I have tried to use the limited understanding I have to troubleshoot where the issue lies, but have so far come up short. I will go show you my code and the area I think the problem lies.

I have already fixed one thing that I noticed, where the varaiable I needed was not the one I used, but I have gone through the code, and can not find any further slip-ups of this kind.

```
import codecs
import re

fileIn = codecs.open("differenceInAbility.xml", "r", "utf-8")
text = fileIn.read()
fileIn.close()

chapterTitle = re.findall(r'<chapter number="(\d)" name="(.+?)">', text)
chapters = re.findall(r'<chapter number="\d" name=".+?">(.+?)</chapter>', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
paragraphs = re.findall(r"<paragraph>(.+?)</paragraph>", text, flags=re.DOTALL)

cleanParagraphs = []
for entry in paragraphs:
    cleanup = re.sub(r"\r\n[ ]+", " ", entry)
    cleanup2 = re.sub(r"[ ]+", " ", cleanup)
    cleanParagraphs.append(cleanup2)
chaptersHTML = []
chapterCounter = 1
for entry in chapters:
    if chapterTitle[0] == r"\d+":
        chapterHTML = "<h1> Chapter " + chapterCounter + " - " + chapterTitle[1] + "</h1>"
        chapterTitle.pop(0)
        chapterTitle.pop(1)
        paragraphsHTML = []
        for paragraph in cleanParagraphs:
            if paragraph in entry:
                p = "<p>" + paragraph + "</p>"
                paragraphsHTML.append(p)
        allParagraphsHTML = "\n".join(paragraphsHTML)
        wholeSection = chapterHTML + allParagraphsHTML
        chaptersHTML.append(wholeSection)
        chapterCounter += 1


print(chaptersHTML)
```

The part I believe are relevant, is:

```
 paragraphsHTML = []
        for paragraph in cleanParagraphs:
            if paragraph in entry:
                p = "<p>" + paragraph + "</p>"
                paragraphsHTML.append(p)
        allParagraphsHTML = "\n".join(paragraphsHTML)
        wholeSection = chapterHTML + allParagraphsHTML
        chaptersHTML.append(wholeSection)
```

because the `cleanParagraphs` list has the right content, where each paragraph of the xml document is its own entry in this list.

Could the problem be `if paragraph in entry`because it doesn't register parts of the "entry" as the paragraph within it?

If so, how would I go about solving this? How do I make sure it knows which paragraph is in what chapter?

Comment: provide a [mcve] or do some basic debugging. put a print at the append, if you don't have a debugger. You haven't demonstrated that there is anything that meets the condition to actually get appended.

Comment: Kenny: The mininal, complete and varifiable is what I tried to do. I'm still pretty new to coding, and the second part of the code was the most minimal I could get to. I suspect that the reasons it didn't append is, like I said in the post, that the if statement ```if pragaraph in entry``` doesnt apply because ```entry``` is one big string, and ```paragraph``` is smaller strings I am trying to ask if ar in entry, and that the  ``ìf ... in``` does't capture one string within another string, but I can't be sure, which is why I added that and asked if that could be the problem, and how to fix it.

Comment: The code is pretty good for a mcve, if you provide a small xml file. But the important part is just stepping through and seeing if things do what you expect. Are there any chapters? Do the paragraphs match what you are matching them to? You don't need to suspect -- put a debug print there and know.

Comment: I will also suggest you get an xml parser. Trying to do your own xml with regex is very fragile.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `cleanParagraphs` are not the original substrings, so of course they do not appear in the unaltered `chapters` values.  You should process each chapter (including breaking it into paragraphs) separately, so that you don’t have to rediscover which paragraphs it contains (and to avoid mishandling paragraphs that happen to be identical between two chapters).